# Is there an API for private comments in Google Classroom?

Tags: google-classroom

When teachers return a student submission they can leave a private comment to the student (and vice versa). Is there an API to retrieve that ? I cannon find it in the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/return

Answer (score 4):

There's no direct method for this from the Classroom API. There's only the [Grade student responses](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-coursework) where you can grade the student's work. You can either [file a feature request](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request) or write your own implementation.

Comment: You might want to include in your answer the related issue from the Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36882823